# Qual a origem do ditado "Boi preto conhece boi preto."?

Tags: origem-histórica, ditados, ditado-popular

Escutei pela primeira vez o ditado e fiquei muito curioso sobre sua origem:

> “Boi preto conhece boi preto”.

Encontrei o mesmo numa frase do Clodovil Hernandes que diz assim:

> “Da fruta que eu gosto, o Leonardo di Caprio chupa até o caroço. Falo
> isso porque boi preto conhece boi preto.”

Qual é o significado deste ditado? Qual a sua origem histórica?

Comment: Não conheço o ditado, mas parece indicar que iguais se reconhecem. É o que o contexto do exemplo de uso sugere.

Comment: Estou quase certo que ele **"parafraseou"** isso.

Comment: Grande @GuilhermeNascimento ... então, ontem foi a primeira vez que ouvi aqui no trampo. Achei curioso a colocação do meu colega aqui no momento em que falou. Parece mesmo que foi parafraseada, mas não da para ter certeza.

Comment: Pesquisando na Internet, encontrei um site (https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/boi-preto-conhece-boi-preto.3038035/) que contém alguma dica de significado: “Existe um ditado popular que é ‘Boi preto conhece Boi Preto’, que significa algo algo como:
‘Malandro (re)conhece Malandro’ ou ‘trambiqueiro (re)conhece trambiqueiro’”. Logo, indica-se que @stafusa está certo.

Comment: Sobre a origem, não a sei, mas creio ser vinda do Clodovil. Se ele não a inventou, ele provavelmente popularizou.

Comment: Nunca ouvi, e acredito não ser um ditado popular na minha região.  Pode até ter sido criado pelo próprio Clodovil, e muitas variações são possíveis: "raposa conhece raposa", "falsário conhece falsário".  Tudo em cima do mesmo tema: dois iguais se reconhecem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao que tudo indica, a frase *boi preto conhece boi preto* foi criada pelo próprio Clodovil Hernandes numa entrevista à revista *Veja* em 8 de fevereiro de 2006. Digo isto porque:

1. Vários artigos posteriores atribuem *boi preto conhece boi preto* a Clodovil Hernades, como estes no [Jornal do Brasil (29-1-2008)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=030015_12&pesq=%22boi%20preto%20conhece%22&pasta=ano%20200&pagfis=225830) e no [Correio Braziliense (24-9-2008)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=028274_05&pesq=%22boi%20preto%20conhece%22&pasta=ano%20200&pagfis=203641). Este no [Plantão de Ponta Grossa (23-3-2010)](http://www.plantaodacidade.com.br/Anteriores/terca230310/ramalho.htm) afirma que a frase “[n]ão é uma criação do meio rural, muito ao contrário, é uma metáfora zoológica de Clodovil”. E estoutro n’[O Explorador (24-4-2019)](https://www.oexplorador.com.br/da-fruta-que-eu-gosto-o-leonardo-di-caprio-come-ate-o-caroco-sei-disso-porque-boi-preto-conhece-boi-preto-clodovil-estilista-em-entrevista-a-amaury-junior-dizendo-que-o-casament/) dá-nos a referência exata: entrevista a Amaury Júnior na *Veja* nº 5, 8 de fevereiro de 2006, p. 40/41.
2. Não encontrei em lado nenhum a frase antes de 2006. Procurei no Google geral, Google Books, na [Hemeroteca Digital Brasileira](http://memoria.bn.br/hdb/periodico.aspx), que tem o texto integral de centenas de periódicos brasileiros dos últimos duzentos anos, e nada.
3. Das várias pessoas que se pronunciaram, ver comentários à pergunta, quase ninguém conhecia a frase.

[O Explorador](https://www.oexplorador.com.br/da-fruta-que-eu-gosto-o-leonardo-di-caprio-come-ate-o-caroco-sei-disso-porque-boi-preto-conhece-boi-preto-clodovil-estilista-em-entrevista-a-amaury-junior-dizendo-que-o-casament/) conta que Clodovil nessa entrevista de 2006 afirmou que o casamento de Leonardo di Caprio com Gisele Bündchen não deu certo porque ele é gay. E que ele, Clodovil, sabe isso porque “boi preto conhece boi preto”: Clodovi, gay assumido, sabe ver se outro homem é também gay.

A frase foi depois usada a propósito de outro tipo de pessoas. Por exemplo, no [Plantão de Ponta Grossa (2010)](http://www.plantaodacidade.com.br/Anteriores/terca230310/ramalho.htm) é a propósito de político conhecer outro político. Mas pessoal escrevendo sobre homossexualidade teve naturalmente uma predileção por ela. Por exemplo, este [“Ensaio sobre o radar ou Boi preto conhece boi preto” (Inconfidências íntimas,1-12-2010)](http://inconfidenciasintimas.blogspot.com/2010/11/ensaio-sobre-o-radar-ou-boi-preto.html); o título refere-se à alegada capacidade de um gay “encontrar outros *gays* mesmo em ambientes eminentemente *heteronormativos*”.

Como observado nos comentários à pergunta, a noção pode ser expressa de mil maneiras diferentes, e é bem possível que o Clodovil tivesse simplesmente adaptado uma frase já ouvida. Por exemplo, no [Monitor Mercantil em 2003](https://monitormercantil.com.br/marcelo-beauty-lanua-kit-de-produtos-para-maquiagem%20) temos “Ladrão conhece ladrão”, apresentado como mais ou menos equivalente ao “provérbio americano ‘Set a Thief to Catch a Thief’”. E temos “malandro conhece malandro no olho” (que imagino exprima a mesma ideia) já em 1979 neste [*Manuscrito do heróico empregadinho de bordel* de Mário Lago](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1366&bih=625&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk01hIgpJsn3QJVjBh8tLYdAhGgR4xQ%3A1606560552233&ei=KCvCX_TtDdO7lwTAy4vgDQ&q=%22malandro%20conhece%20malandro%20no%20olho%22&oq=%22malandro%20conhece%20malandro%20no%20olho%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...491208.495674.0.496223.10.10.0.0.0.0.151.1214.1j9.10.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.124...33i10k1.0.XW8Ftm-7V9o).

Answer (score 1):

O exemplo dado é uma [figura de linguagem plurissignificativa](https://www.portugues.com.br/gramatica/figuras-estilo-ou-linguagem.html), em todos os casos naturalista e biológica. Podemos dizer que tem ambiguidade por conter um duplo sentido que não pode ser inteiramente resolvido.

Permite simultaneamente uma interpretação em sentido literal e em sentido figurado. Se figurado é uma [metáfora](https://dicionario.priberam.org/metafora) [zoomórphica](https://dicionario.priberam.org/zoom%C3%B3rficas) em que associamos características do animal à pessoa, se em sentido literal remete para as características do animal no seu todo.

O jogo de sentidos é deixado em aberto, embora mantendo um duplo sentido estrito, com uma semántica tão vasta quantos sentidos e características possamos ou queiramos associar ao animal nomeado. A semántica essencial é:"semelhante reconhece semelhante".

Por outro lado é minimalista em termos sintáticos, o jogo de palavras assenta **na seguinte estrutura fixa**: a repetição do [nome comum](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/nome-comumconcreto/2861) de uma espécie de animal (variável) -nos comentários foi dado outro exemplo com adjectivo em vez de substantivo- em torno de uma verbo fixo *"conhece"* ou o seu derivado por prefixação [*"reconhece"*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/Conjugar/reconhecer) sempre conjugados na 3ª pessoa do singular do pretérito presente do indicativo de *"reconhecer"*. A adjectivação é uma redundância, portanto um [pleonasmo](https://www.infoescola.com/linguistica/pleonasmo/); O boi ser preto ou branco particulariza mas não faz diferença - nada acescenta.

O conjunto não constitui um ditado popular, excepto talvez se for um [provincianismo](https://dicionario.priberam.org/regionalismo) restrito no espaço a uma sociedade particular. Constitui sim uma figura de linguagem, nisso é universal, e deve a sua força à simplicidade [mnemónica](https://dicionario.priberam.org/mnem%C3%B3nica).